# Tabs switch triggering on click

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick

I need to switch tabs in an HTML/CSS Tabs widget by clicking on a specific button.
For this I'm trying to aim to specific element on the page by using `document.querySelector` and then to remove using `element.classList.remove` `tab-current` class which makes a specific tab to be active and then add the same class using `element.classList.add` to another element of the widget related to another tab. But apperently I'm doing something wrong because the tabs aren't switching with the clicked button.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
      jQuery('#button a').click(function() {
          document.querySelector("#premium-tabs-aa81ee4 > div.premium-tabs-nav > ul > li:nth-child(1) > a").element.classList.remove("tab-current");
          document.querySelector("#premium-tabs-aa81ee4 > div:nth-child(1) > ul:nth-child(1) > li:nth-child(2)").element.classList.add("tab-current");
        }
      }
```

```html
<div id="premium-tabs-aa81ee4" class="premium-tabs premium-tabs-style-flip premium-tabs-horizontal">
  <div class="premium-tabs-nav">
    <ul class="premium-tabs-nav-list premium-tabs-horizontal">
      <li class="premium-tabs-nav-list-item tab-current" style="pointer-events: auto;">
        <a class="premium-tab-link" href="#section-flip-0-aa81ee4">
          <span class="premium-tab-title">Tab 1</span> </a>
      </li>
      <li class="premium-tabs-nav-list-item" style="pointer-events: auto;">
        <a class="premium-tab-link" href="#section-flip-1-aa81ee4">
          <span class="premium-tab-title" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51);">Tab 2</span> </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What does .tab-current class do?

Comment: Determines which tab's content to show and highlights the active tab

Comment: Looks like you have a syntax error in your JavaScript. Click Run code snippet.

Comment: I didn't paste the part of the code related to the tabs' content because I think if switching the tabs with the button will work I'll add a couple of js lines related to triggering of tabs' content. Thanks.

Comment: I think it's because there's no button in his part of code with the id #button. But could it be also the error in the querySelectors ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`className` did the trick I wanted on the appropriate selectors:

`className = "premium-tabs-nav-list-item";`

`className = "premium-tabs-nav-list-item tab-current";`

Answer (score 0):

Basically they is no need for a button all you just need is to add the class "tab-current" to any list item that was click. 
    `<script>
       $(document).ready(function (){
       $('.premium-tabs-nav-list-item').click( function () {
        $('.premium-tabs-nav-list-item').removeClass('tab-current') ;
        $(this).addClass('tab-current');
      });
      }) ;
      </script>`

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.

Comment: Sorry am kind of new here, since i didn't write much code i was not expecting to explain except been ask for clarification